# .net отправка файла через сокет

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, сокет

Как можно отправить файл с Клиента на Сервер? Есть еще проблема, возможно ли с помощью http debugger-ов просмотреть запрос и подключиться к серверу не через приложение, а через самописную программу и тем самым нагрузить на сервер куча файлов, если да, как исправить?

Comment: какое приложение, какие файлы отправляет?

Comment: @KoVadim, текстовые файлы, приложение я пишу из-за задания учителя

Comment: Есть приложение Fiddler, которое умеет смотреть и отправлять HTTP пакеты. Есть низкоуровневый `Socket`, а есть готовый `HttpClient`. Первый нужен тогда, когда вы реализуете свой протокол. Второй - когда используете HTTP(S), не перепутайте. Точнее, вы скорее уже перепутали.

Comment: Скорее всего, вы хотите REST API с аутентификацией. Хотя ещё об этом не знаете.